# Error from simply initializing a variable?

Tags: python, recursion, boggle

While putting together a Boggle solver, I ran into some strange behavior I was hoping someone could explain to me. I got the function to return a set of possible words, and all I seemed to be missing was a way to prevent the solver from including words which were created by visiting the same square twice in a play. I tried to create a list of already visited squares within the current play (a list of index numbers within the string representing the board) by iterating over the global variable `seen` (I know this would not be correct) which is used to memoize previously explored paths. However, simply initializing a variable with those values using:

```
previous_ind = [j for (pre, j) in seen]
```

within the recursive function `find_bwords`, somehow effects the index variable `i` and causes IndexErrors stemming from the last line in find_bwords.

```
seen = set() #(prefix, index) pairs

def boggle_words(board, minlength=3):
    "Find all the words on this Boggle board; return as a set of words."
    results = set()
    for i, sq in enumerate(board):
        if is_letter(sq):
            find_bwords(board, sq, i, results, minlength)
    return results

def find_bwords(board, pre, start, results, minlength): #adds to seen and results
    global seen
    #prev_ind = [j for (pre, j) in seen]  <---mystery culprit
    if (pre, start) not in seen:
        seen.add((pre, start))
        if len(pre) >= minlength and pre in WORDS:
            results.add(pre)
        if pre in PREFIXES:
            for i in neighbors(start, int(sqrt(len(board)))):
                #print 'index: ', i
                find_bwords(board, pre+board[i], i, results, minlength)
```

Here is a portion of the printout of indexes before introducing `prev_ind`:

```
index:  0
index:  1
index:  2
index:  6
index:  8
index:  12
index:  13
index:  14
index:  1
index:  2
```

and here is a portion after:

```
index:  0
index:  -7
index:  -14
index:  -21
index:  -28
index:  -35
index:  -42
```

Why is this happening?

To be clear, I am not looking for a solution to this assignment, I have solved it another way, I just want to understand what is happening in this instance.

Comment: Can you paste in the traceback for the exception? Ideally, could you provide a reproducible example (that is, a board, pre, start, etc)?

Comment: Also, why isn't the `previous_ind` line you describe in the code? Where was it located in the code? I'm sure that line wasn't actually affecting the value of `i`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson it is in the code, commented out on the 3rd line in find_bwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line you are assigning to `pre`, overwriting the previous value it had:

```
prev_ind = [j for (pre, j) in seen]  # <---mystery culprit
```

Try changing it to this and it should work as you expect:

```
prev_ind = [j for (pre2, j) in seen]
```

Comment: Beat me by two seconds, +1. Python refrains from introducing new scopes to enhance speed, but it can be unintuitive sometimes.

Comment: In Python 3 it's fixed: this unexpected behaviour no longer happens.